# Angular service to return true or false if the route has queryParams ¿How to handle the subscription?

Tags: angular, rxjs, boolean, guard

I'm creating a guard in Angular that have to return true or false if the route has query params or not.

I've create a service like this that return an Observable true or false:

```
export class MatchService {
  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {}
  validateQuerys(): Observable<boolean> {
    return this.route.queryParams.pipe(
      map(res => {
        return res['name'] ? true:false;
      })
    )
  }
}
```

And now the problem, how to handle it in my canMatch guard?

```
export class routeMatcher implements CanMatch {

  constructor(private matchService: MatchService) {}

  canMatch(): boolean {

    this.matchService.validateQuerys().subscribe({
      next: res => (console.log(res))
      // return?
      // ¿How I can return true or false?
    })

   }
}
```

The problem is that I do not know where to place the return true or false in the canMatch() function.

Comment: canMatch is a niche guard. Why are you using it ? Could you give more context about your goal ?

Comment: I have two routes at the same level, just one have query params, and I want to load different components depends on if have query params or not. So I think canMatch is a good approach

Comment: Indeed it is, sorry for asking, canMatch is 1% of the use cases, just wanted to be sure !

Answer (score 2):

Ignoring my comment, your solution is as simple as that.

```js
return this.matchService.validateQuerys().pipe(first());
```

Delete your return type on your function to avoid typing errors, because anyways, the function type is inferred from the parent

Comment: But if I do that, I am not subscribing to anything, it does not work...

Comment: You don’t have to subscribe. A guard can return `Observable<Boolean>`. However, you may need to add a `.pipe(take(1))` to it.

Comment: @BizzyBob thanks, missed that, added it just before seeing your comment !

Comment: Hi :) I need the guard here:{
path: '', canMatch: [homeMatcher], component:ProductsPageComponent},
But the Observable<boolean> is not working, Can i return true or false?

Comment: The signature of the guard accepts an observable. If it does not work, please provide more information. And no, you cannot return true or false with an observable.